# How to silence ThriftAccessLogger in apache Storm when using LocalCluster?

Tags: log4j, apache-storm

It's so verbose, I'm trying to define a topology and print my own stuff, but it's impossible to do it with so much noise!

Answer (score 0):

Add following to `log4j.properties` file.
`log4j.logger.org.apache.storm.logging.ThriftAccessLogger=WARN`

It sets logging level to WARN for ThriftAccessLogger class. And all messages below WARN level will be filtered.